# Annotate R base plot with grid when the base plot is in a grid viewport

Tags: r

In a complex figure, I position a R base plot at a specific position (in a grid viewport). So far, everything works.

However, I then am unable to annotate this figure using grid commands; basically, I do not manage to set up the coordinate system so that the "native" coordinates work in grid commands.

Here is a minimal example that illustrates what I am trying:

```
library(gridBase)
library(grid)

pushViewport(viewport(x = .4, y = .4, width = .6, height = .6))

par(plt = gridPLT())
xpos <- barplot(c(7,8,9,5))   

## up to here everything works. The problems begin when I try to place labels
## under the bars. Here, I would like to use 'xpos', i.e. to barplot's native 
## coordinates

## for a figure not already in a viewport, I would push viewports like this:
vps <- baseViewports()
pushViewport(vps$vps$inner, vps$figure, vps$plot)

## these labels appear at the wrong place:
grid.text(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), x = unit(xpos, "native"), y = unit(1, "lines"))

popViewport(0)
```

How do I set up a grid viewport so that the "native" coordinates correspond to the ones used in the barplot?

(Of course, I can do the coordinate transformation myself using par("usr"), which works, but it would be great not to have to do this myself)

**REPLY TO ANSWER BY Allan Cameron:**: This does not work for me. Only when I "manually" calculate the coordinates (fromUX) do I get the right position:

```
library(gridBase)
library(grid)

fromUX <- function(x) {
    x0 <- par("usr")[1]
    x1 <- par("usr")[2]
    dx <- x1 - x0
    (x - x0) / dx
}

pushViewport(viewport(x = .4, y = .4, width = .6, height = .6))

par(plt = gridPLT())
xpos <- barplot(c(7,8,9,5))

grid.text(c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
    x = fromUX(xpos),
    y = unit(2, "lines")
)

vps <- baseViewports()

pushViewport(vps$plot)

grid.text(c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
    x = unit(xpos, "native"),
    y = unit(1, "lines")
)

popViewport(0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply need to push the "plot" viewport:

```r
library(gridBase)
library(grid)

pushViewport(viewport(x = .4, y = .4, width = .6, height = .6))

par(plt = gridPLT())
xpos <- barplot(c(7,8,9,5))   

vps <- baseViewports()

pushViewport(vps$plot)

grid.text(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 
          x = unit(xpos, "native"), 
          y = unit(1, "lines"))
```

[image]

Comment: this does not work for me, see update added to original question above

Comment: @user52366 In that case, I can't replicate your problem. I have run my code in fresh R sessions on two different machines and get exactly the output shown.

Comment: I am on linux, using R 4.3.2 from CRAN, and it does neither work in the "direct" output on the screen, nor in a pdf created with cairo_pdf(). Also reproducible on different computers... this is strange...